# Uploading a file does not work properly in Django

Tags: python, django, forms

I'm just starting to work with `Django-Multiupload`.

I have a problem - when I try to upload file/files, it seems that it works but no file is being uploaded in fact.

**VIEWS.PY**

```
def index(request):
    multiple_file_upload_form = MultipleFileUploadForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
         print request.FILES 

    return render(request,'index.html',
                  context={'file_upload_form':multiple_file_upload_form})
```

**INDEX.HTML**

```
<form action="" method="post"> {% csrf_token %}
       {{ multiple_file_upload_form | crispy }}
       <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

**FORMS.PY**

```
class MultipleFileUploadForm(forms.Form):
    attachments = MultiFileField(min_num=1)
```

After choosing some file from my PC and clicking on submit, there is `<MultiValueDict: {}>` in `cmd`.

Do you know why?

**EDIT:**

After changing view code:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
        if multiple_file_upload_form.is_valid():
            print 'ok'
            print request.FILES
        else:
            print multiple_file_upload_form.errors
```

It print's that field `attachements` is required. But I've fill it (file has been chosen).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include enctype in your form: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_enctype.asp

`<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">`